# Electron-Builder is there an option to pass custom agruments to signtool.exe?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, codesign, signtool

I've an Electron application, for which we create an installer using electron-builder. Under the covers, I believe, electron-builder calls out to the Windows `signtool.exe`. I've a need to pass in a custom argument to this tool.

Are there any options available other than writing a custom sign script with the `sign` build argument. i.e. https://www.electron.build/configuration/win#WindowsConfiguration-sign

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, I could not find anyway to achieve the above. I instead used the [sign](https://www.electron.build/configuration/win#WindowsConfiguration-sign) override, which is user friendly.